# Python several plots on the same plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I have a dataframe called df:

```
IdDeviceType . NameDevice    IdBox    value    hour
   471          Heater        4       0.3       3 
   486          Thermo        5       0.6       14
   492          Censor        8       0.8       22
```

I would like to plot the heater and the thermo mean value grouped by hour per flat (a flat is an IdBox number).

```
def my_plot(df2, x1, x2, idbox):
   dev_id1 = df2['NameDevice'].isin(x1)
   df2 = df2[dev_id]
   print (set(df2.value.values))
   vals1 = [df2[df2['IdBox'] == idb].groupby('hour')['value'].mean()
        for idb in idbox]
  for val1 in vals1:
    plot1 = plt.plot(val1.values)

    dev_id2 = df2['NameDevice'].isin(x2)
    df2 = df2[dev_id]
    print (set(df2.value.values))
    vals2 = [df2[df2['IdBox'] == idb].groupby('hour')['value'].mean()
        for idb in idboxe]
  for val2 in vals2:
    plot2 = plt.plot(vals2.values)

plt.xlabel('hour')
plt.ylabel('mean Value')
plt.show() 

my_plot(df, ['Heater'],['Thermo'], [7])
```

Comment: `plt.show()` needs to be outside the for-loop. If this is not the issue, you need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I changed it to make it clear

Comment: This is **not** a [mcve]. And it will not work because you call `plt.show()`before calling your `my_plot2`function.

Answer (score 0):

according to http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html you should just be able to something like this:

```
t = np.arange(0., 5., 0.2)

# red dashes, blue squares and green triangles
plt.plot(t, t, 'r--', t, t**2, 'bs', t, t**3, 'g^')
plt.show()
```

you just use the foramt: `(x,y, style, x, y, style.....)` over and over